# Could not find or load main class -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8090

Tags: java, jmx

I am trying to run jconsole to see the beans working but in the jconsole they aren't visible so I tried with jmx but getting the following error?

Could not find or load main class -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8090

This is the command that I run ob my Linux Terminal

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \ -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 \ -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \ -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \ -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Comment: your java command is missing the main class

Comment: what if I want to exceute my Java application using tomcat, can I put this command in setenv.sh and then run this, will that work?

Comment: yes, edit catalina.sh or create a setenv.sh, both will work

Comment: Ok I tried this and worked Thanks Fran

Comment: Glad to hear! :)